# Strange path shown in exception when JVM crashes

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, unsafe

After running code such as

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    getUnsafe().getByte(0);
}

private static Unsafe getUnsafe() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
    return (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
}
```

which causes the JVM to crash, then having a look at the logged output, under the Internal exceptions section some strange paths are shown:

```
    thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u60\4407\hotspot\srÚÞ ©Ö_®?
    thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u60\4407\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\j
```

I definitely don't have these paths on my local machine, and some googling shows that they end up in these crash dumps fairly often. I assume they're from when the JDK was originally compiled.

My question is - is that correct? And why is this information baked into the JDK? Purely for debugging later?

Comment: This is what happens when Unsafe is Unhappy, :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is that correct?

I assume so.

> And why is this information baked into the JDK? Purely for debugging later?

Yes, the original paths are stored in some compiled images for C/C++ for analysing a core dump.

One way to avoid these crashes is to use a library which wraps Unsafe and makes sure you only access valid regions of memory. e.g. [Chronicle-Bytes](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes) does this for 64-bit memory sizes with thread safe access for binary and text data. (Disclaimer, I helped write it)

Comment: @EvanKnowles if you are interested in Unsafe and off heap you might find this library interesting as Chronicle-Queue and Chronicle-Map are built in it and are off heap data stores which uses this extensively.